# Zapier: BigCommerce to Google Sheet, New Row for Each Item

Tags: google-sheets, bigcommerce, zapier

I have successfully linked my BigCommerce account to my Google Sheets (Drive) account so every time I receive a new order in my store the order is automatically exported into a Google Sheet. Unfortunately, an entire order is listed on one row with multiple items added into one cell. What I need is to have each product on its own row; for example, if someone orders three different products Zapier would create three new rows. This functionality exists when directly exporting orders from BigCommerce, but the "Zap" does not use the BigCommerce export function when pulling order information from my store to the Google Sheet.

I know this is a shot in the dark, but I am hoping someone might have a solution that I can implement. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You definitely can split the order into the several rows ... but I can't tell if this can be done within the Zap (never used Zapier) or as a second pass, i.e. either a Google Apps script is run once the order arrives; or even a spreadsheet formula splits up the order into a second sheet, automatically.  Do you have a sheet per order, or does Zap keep   adding each order to the same sheet? More information is required for us that haven't used Zapier before.  Also a (dummy but precise) copy of the order spreadsheet would be necessary.

Comment: 1. Re: Google Apps Script - I considered that as an option; the products are separated by a comma within each cell so a script could be created to split the data similarly to Excel's "text to columns" function, but I was trying to avoid something custom as such.

Comment: 2. Dummy Example - I've created a fake example of what I am trying to achieve and what is currently happening: [https://docs.google.com/a/perfectpixelmarketing.com/spreadsheets/d/17A4661YqYzb0NWXUEMmHzIKkDEdzpu_HoexXOUSEqFs/edit?usp=sharing].

Comment: 3. Re: Sheet per Order - The Zap creates a new row on the same worksheet; that might be the default setting. I do not know if I am able to make changes to the workflow.

Comment: Can you give access to the sheet you have shared?

Comment: You should be able to view the Google Sheet now.

Comment: It was too tough for me to help via a formula, sorry.  I have added a script as an answer, which might help you get by.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script that perhaps could be used or modified, at least until you find if the process can be done within Zapier.

You can try the script in the following ss: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ggNYlLEeN3UYtZC_KlOGwpyII9CzOLKMnIOKIDrPJPM/edit?usp=sharing

The script assumes that orders arrive in the tab named Zapier. As things are set up, you would run the script through the Custom Menu.

If there are 2 orders or more, click the menu for each order.

The complete rows appear in the sheet FullList.

(if you want to play/try again, you will have to manually delete the rows in FullList once they are showing).

```
function processForNewOrders() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Zapier');
  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName('FullList');

  var sourceValues = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var destinationValues = destinationSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var index = [];
  destinationValues.forEach( function (x) {
    index.push(x[0]);
  })
  var newOrders = [];
  for (var y = sourceValues.length -1 ; y > 0 ; y --){
    if(sourceValues[y][0].toString().indexOf('po_number') != -1 ) continue;
    var i = index.indexOf(sourceValues[y][0]);
    if(i != -1) break; // This readies only the fresh orders for processing
    newOrders.push(sourceValues[y]);
  }

  Logger.log(newOrders)
  for (var j = 0 ; j < newOrders.length ; j++){
    var output = [];
    var orderLine = newOrders[j];
    Logger.log('orderLine = ' + orderLine);
    var circuit = 0;
    var items = 1
    while (circuit < items){
      var row = [];
      for (var z = 0 ; z < orderLine.length; z++){
        var cell = orderLine[z];
        //      Logger.log(cell);
        var lines = cell.toString().split(',');
        if(lines.length > 1)  items = lines.length;
        row.push(lines[circuit] ? lines[circuit] : lines[0]);
        //      Logger.log('row =' + row);
      }
      circuit ++;
      Logger.log('circuit circuit circuit =' + circuit)

      output.push(row);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(output);
  if(output != undefined)
  destinationSheet.getRange(index.length+1,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output);
}


function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Process new order', 'processForNewOrders')
            .addToUi();
}
```

Comment: Wow - that is awesome. I'll play around with it soon and will let you know how it works. Thank you for your help!